# Is this an efficient way of doing a linq query with dynamic order by fields?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method to apply a sort to a list of objects (simplified it for the example):

```
private IEnumerable<Something> SetupOrderSort(IEnumerable<Something> input,
    SORT_TYPE sort)
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<Something> output = input.OrderBy(s => s.FieldA).
        ThenBy(s => s.FieldB);
    switch (sort)
    {
        case SORT_TYPE.FIELD1:
            output = output.ThenBy(s => s.Field1);
            break;
        case SORT_TYPE.FIELD2:
            output = output.ThenBy(s => s.Field2);
            break;
        case SORT_TYPE.UNDEFINED:
            break;
    }
    return output.ThenBy(s => s.FieldC).ThenBy(s => s.FieldD).
        AsEnumerable();
}
```

What I needs is to be able to insert a specific field in the midst of the orby clause.  By default the ordering is: FIELDA, FIELDB, FIELDC, FIELDD.

When a sort field is specified though I need to insert the specified field between FIELDB and FIELDC in the sort order.

Currently there is only 2 possible fields to sort by but could be up to 8.  Performance wise is this a good approach?  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

**EDIT:** I saw the following thread as well: [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244) but I thought it was overkill for what I needed.  This is a snippet of code that executes a lot so I just want to make sure I am not doing something that could be easily done better that I am just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inefficient about your method, but there is something *unintuitive* about it, which is that you can't sort by *multiple* columns - something that end users are almost sure to want to do.

I might hand-wave this concern away on the chance that both columns are unique, but the fact that you subsequently hard-code in another sort at the end leads me to believe that `Field1` and `Field2` are neither related nor unique, in which case you really should consider the possibility of having an arbitrary number of levels of sorting, perhaps by accepting an `IEnumerable<SORT_TYPE>` or `params SORT_TYPE[]` argument instead of a single `SORT_TYPE`.

Anyway, as far as performance goes, the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extensions have **deferred execution**, so each successive `ThenBy` in your code is probably no more than a few CPU instructions, it's just wrapping one function in another.  It will be fine; the actual sorting will be far more expensive.

Comment: The sorting method has been spec'd by the users/client so it is how they need it to work. 99% the `SORT_TYPE` will be undefined but they need to sort in a specific way in very specific scenarios. Your comment about the deferred execution is something I didn't realize so thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and "optimize" stuff you haven't proved slow with a profiler.

It's highly unlikely that this will be slow enough to notice. I strongly suspect the overhead of actually sorting the list is higher than switching on one string.

The important question is: Is this code maintainable? Will you forget to add another `case` the next time you add a property to `Something`? If that will be a problem, consider using the MS Dynamic Query sample, from the VS 2008 C# samples page.

Otherwise, you're fine.

Comment: agreed, micro optimizations should only take place when they are extremely necessary. The more important things to look out for are maintainability and complexity

Comment: Agreed. Simplicity is always best IMO and this is as simple as I can get it I think. This executes a lot though in relation to the app so I thought I would spend a little bit of time making sure it was efficient.

Comment: That's fine. Profile it. This will quickly tell you how much time the `switch` takes. Since you return an `IEnumerable`, the sort will be done outside this method. I'm betting the overhead of the `switch` is barely measurable.